# RxSwift Input Output, private subject but being triggered outside the class

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Im reading this blog about the input output ViewModel approach:
https://medium.com/blablacar-tech/rxswift-mvvm-66827b8b3f10

full code: https://gist.github.com/MartinMoizard

Im just puzzled on how did the

```
let greeting = validateSubject
        .withLatestFrom(nameSubject)
        .map { name in
            return "Hello \(name)!"
        }
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: ":-(")
```

https://gist.github.com/MartinMoizard/4d66528a9959cbbdefa6d50394d2bfb1

is being triggered if the **validateSubject** is private upon tapped in 
https://gist.github.com/MartinMoizard/449be0d30920010210988f1773a2ca90

```
final class ButtonCell: UITableViewCell, SayHelloViewModelBindable {
    @IBOutlet weak var validateButton: UIButton!
    var disposeBag: DisposeBag?

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        disposeBag = nil
    }

    func bind(to viewModel: SayHelloViewModel) {
        let bag = DisposeBag()
        validateButton.rx
            .tap
            .bind(to: viewModel.input.validate)
            .disposed(by: bag)
        disposeBag = bag
    }
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is not really accessing `validateSubject` upon `tap` but eventually he has created some **accessible input/output layer** see for example:

```
struct Input {
   let name: AnyObserver<String>
   let validate: AnyObserver<Void>
} 

struct Output {
   let greeting: Driver<String>
}
```

to communicate with the inner private layer/logic (such as `validateSubject` and `nameSubject`).

And then he pass all kind of information in input through `name` and `validate` and expect information back from the output through `greeting`.

Comment: thank you for your reply, so you mean the `validateSubject` will be kind of a proxy for the validate? so if we will be passing the `name` and `validate` the `validateSubject` will still run?

Comment: Not sure if we can call `validateSubject` a kind of proxy for the `validate` input field, but for sure your `ViewModel` will act as an adapter as it converts an Input (name and validation) to an Output (greeting) expected by the client that is consuming the ViewModel. How that is accomplished is exactly by bindings and events (through Subjects, Observers and Drivers).